# My website sitemap.xml file suddenly includes thousands of spam links of my own domain

Tags: xml, wordpress, plugins, sitemap

I'm using word press with Go-daddy, I noticed yesterday that my sitemap file contains allot of spam, i have no idea where they came from, before my sitemap contain only around 300 pages now it contain 27000+. How should i remove them i tried to find sitemap editors but could not find a suitable plugin or manual way to those links. Any help would be appriciated. This is my sitemap link [enter link description here](http://magfocus.com/sitemap.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Well i solved the problem. I deleted the sitemap.xml file from my webhosting account manually and then generate it again with wordpress plugin. I think it is hit by some kind of spam so i reset all my passwords. Now site map look okay. If any one having the same problem he can do the same. Chao